# Ubuntu has received an error when installing DevStack in OpenStack

Tags: 18.04

1. Ubuntu has received an error when installing DevStack in OpenStack.

   ```
   stack@denny-pc:~$ cd /opt/devstack/`
   `
   stack@denny-pc:/opt/devstack$ ./stack.sh 
   `
   `
   ```

   File permissions:

   ```
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 43892 1 month   8 18:35 stack.sh*
   ```
2. When it reaches line 605, the following message is displayed:

   ```
   +./stack.sh:read_password:605              set +o xtrace
   touch: cannot touch '/opt/devstack/.localrc.password': Permission denied
   Error on exit
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/opt/devstack/tools/worlddump.py", line 22, in <module>
       from distutils import spawn
   ImportError: cannot import name 'spawn'
   ```
3. Line 605 of stack.sh reads:

   ```
   # Generic helper to configure passwords
   function read_password {
       local xtrace
       xtrace=$(set +o | grep xtrace)
       set +o xtrace
       var=$1; msg=$2
       pw=${!var}

       if [[ -f $RC_DIR/localrc ]]; then
           localrc=$TOP_DIR/localrc
       else
           localrc=$TOP_DIR/.localrc.password
       fi

     # If the password is not defined yet, proceed to prompt user for a password.
       if [ ! $pw ]; then
           # If there is no localrc file, create one
           if [ ! -e $localrc ]; then
               touch $localrc
           fi

           # Presumably if we got this far it can only be that our
           # localrc is missing the required password.  Prompt user for a
           # password and write to localrc.

           echo ''
           echo '################################################################################'
           echo $msg
           echo '################################################################################'
           echo "This value will be written to ${localrc} file so you don't have to enter it "
           echo "again.  Use only alphanumeric characters."
      echo "If you leave this blank, a random default value will be used."
           pw=" "
           while true; do
               echo "Enter a password now:"
               read -e $var
               pw=${!var}
               [[ "$pw" = "`echo $pw | tr -cd [:alnum:]`" ]] && break
               echo "Invalid chars in password.  Try again:"
           done
           if [ ! $pw ]; then
               pw=$(generate_hex_string 10)
           fi
           eval "$var=$pw"
           echo "$var=$pw" >> $localrc
       fi
       # restore previous xtrace value
       $xtrace
   }
   ```
4. Main error message：

   ```
   touch: cannot touch '/opt/devstack/.localrc.password': Permission denied
   ```

What is the cause of this problem?